# How to show hiding part of the text in ionic app?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am building an ionic 3 application, there is a problem I cannot show complete text, part of them is hid automatically due to the text has long content.

[image]

then...

[image]

How to show the hiding part of the text in ionic app? As you can see in the above captured screen, part of the time text is hided as ... 
Corresponding code in html is as below:

```
<ion-label> Select Trip </ion-label>
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="tripid" (ionCancel)="onCancel()" (ionChange)="onChange()">
  <ion-option *ngFor="let subtrip of trips" [value]="subtrip.id">
    {{subtrip.startTime}} - {{subtrip.stopTime}}
  </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Comment: Use css to select the field and make it wider. Or break the two date times into two lines.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't clarified but this looks like Ionic 4 code.

The correct way to control this is to use the built in `ion-text-wrap` class:

[CSS Utilities - Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities#text-modification)

I think this need to go on the `ion-option`:

```
<ion-label> Select Trip </ion-label>
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="tripid" (ionCancel)="onCancel()" (ionChange)="onChange()">
  <ion-option class="ion-text-wrap" *ngFor="let subtrip of trips" [value]="subtrip.id">
    {{subtrip.startTime}} - {{subtrip.stopTime}}
  </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

But if not / maybe also on the `ion-select`:

```
<ion-label> Select Trip </ion-label>
<ion-select class="ion-text-wrap" [(ngModel)]="tripid" (ionCancel)="onCancel()" (ionChange)="onChange()">
  <ion-option class="ion-text-wrap" *ngFor="let subtrip of trips" [value]="subtrip.id">
    {{subtrip.startTime}} - {{subtrip.stopTime}}
  </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

## Updated

You have now specified Ionic 3. The `ion-text-wrap` class is for Ionic 4.

In Ionic 3 this was just an attribute called `text-wrap` but I'm not sure if it was limited to certain components. Try replacing:

```
<ion-label> Select Trip </ion-label>
<ion-select text-wrap [(ngModel)]="tripid" (ionCancel)="onCancel()" (ionChange)="onChange()">
  <ion-option text-wrap *ngFor="let subtrip of trips" [value]="subtrip.id">
    {{subtrip.startTime}} - {{subtrip.stopTime}}
  </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Or a combination of one of them maybe.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to add ion-text-wrap in ion-option and ion-select, but it doesn't work. I used ionic 3. Seems it doesn't work for ion select and option

Comment: no `ion-text-wrap` is for ionic4. In ionic 3 this was just an attribute called `text-wrap` but I'm not sure if it was limited to certain components

Comment: ah ok, I dont know then, I'm not using Ionic 3 so I dont know its details that well, good luck

Answer (score 1):

In ionic 3 you need to override the css, this seems to work fine:

```css
.alert-ios .alert-radio-label {
  white-space: unset !important;
}

.alert-md .alert-radio-label {
  white-space: unset !important;
}

.alert-wp .alert-radio-label {
  white-space: unset !important;
}
```

**DEMO: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-p3nxtj?file=pages/home/home.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use adjust the text so that it appears in the next time by setting a class on `ion-option` e.g.-

```
<ion-option class="adjust-text".....

.adjust-text {
    white-space: normal;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

It should work without `overflow: visible` though.

Comment: have you inspected the DOM to see if the css properties are applied or not ?

Answer (score 0):

in your global.css add

```
.alert-radio-label {
  text-overflow: initial !important;
  white-space: pre-line !important;
}
```